# Wohnen versus leben

Tags: word-choice

> Ist es deiner Meinung nach besser, auf dem Land oder in einer Stadt zu *wohnen*/zu *leben*?

Which one sounds more natural, *wohnen* or *leben*? Or are they both valid but with different nuances or connotations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One could argue that "leben" includes living in a house/flat, working, shopping, all in the countryside, whereas "wohnen" could possibly hint at commuting to work in a city, but I don't think any native speaker would give that much thought. So I'd say that the two words can be used completely interchangeably.

Also note that it should be "deiner Meinung nach" because it's Genitiv. (question word: *Wessen* Meinung?) And you could also say "in der Stadt" as a general term, even if not referring to a specific city.

Answer (score 6):

First of all I fully agree with the comments, previously given. 
With the following example you may find a case where one would use `wohnen` and `leben` differently.
Imagine a farmer for example, who works and lives `auf dem Land`, here, I guess, both terms `wohnen` and `leben` fit, but if someone works in the city and sleeps `auf dem Land`, you would rather say `Er arbeitet in der Stadt und wohnt auf dem Land.` One would rather not say `Er arbeitet in der Stadt und lebt auf dem Land.` This is some kind of contradiction, because a major part of his life happens in the city.

Answer (score 4):

> wohnen

Refers more to where your flat/house is located. You emphasize the location of your bed and property.

> leben

Refers more to where you life is happening. This includes your home but also where you work, where you interact with people, where you do sports, where you go out to eat etc.

Thus in your example *auf dem Land wohnen* would emphasize that your house/flat is located in the countryside but *auf dem Land leben* empahsizes that most of your life happens there.

Answer (score 1):

They are both valid and might have a small connotation:

"Ich wohne in der Stadt" vs "Ich lebe in der Stadt"*:

- `wohne` can describe the fact only - and give the hint, that the quality of life might not be best and the (specific or general) circumstances come with a compromise
- `lebe` can describe that you are "having a good life" in town. So your quality of life is measured as good and you see not much compromise.

That small nuance was used once by a furniture store with "wohnst Du noch oder lebst Du schon?".

Just in everyday life I would say "ich wohne" and care not to much about the nuance.

*<sub>I just picked one location</sub>

Comment: Leben kann ebenfalls rein faktisch gemeint sein und verstanden werden. Dass Leben implizit gut Leben bedeutet ist eine Illusion, die eine Marketingmaßnahme suggeriert haben mag - durch Fakten zu stützen ist sie keineswegs. Verzieh die Mundwinkel während Du sagst "Ich lebe auf dem Land ...", und jeder wird raushören, dass es gerade mal ein Überleben ist.

Comment: @userunknown: Betonen kann ich alles wie mir beliebt, um irgendeine Bedeutung zu erreichen. Dennoch gibt es gesellschaftlich bedingt jeweils aktuelle Interpretationen, wie eine Floskel/ein Verb/ein Satzbau mehrheitlich "im Kopfkino" verstanden wird. Vermutlich noch milieuabhängig. m.M.n. ist "mit neutraler Betonung" die Leitlinie für Nuancen-Fragen - kombiniert mit dem persönlichen Eindruck über den gesellschaftlichen Status quo.

Comment: Eben, mit neutraler Betonung ist beides neutral, mit süffisanter Stimme beides süffisant und mit begeisterter Stimme beides begeistert. Analog kann der Kontext die Interpretation kanalisieren - dann ist es der Kontext, der die Interpretation kanalisiert. Die Wörter allein sind es nicht. Dein Kopfkino vielleicht.